# How can I make a breezejs extended entity complete the initializer function before calling subscribed functions?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

In Breezejs I'm extending an entity via `mgr.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Field', null, newField);`.  The function `newField` adds properties to the entity. I create a new entity via `mgr.createEntity` and it works fine.  The new entity is added to a knockout observable array (a breeze generated property). 
Whenever a new entity is created I want to add it to the DOM programmatically, so I subscribe another function to any changes in the above array (using knockout's subscribe for arrays).  The subscribed function is indeed being called after the creation of a new entity.
 The problem is that the subscribed function is called *before* the `newField` initializer, and because it relies on data generated in the initializer - it cannot work properly. 
 My question is: How can I make breeze and knockout synchronize so that any subscribed functions will only be called *after* the entity to which they subscribed has been fully initialized?  I think I can use the [rate-limit extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) as a workaround, but I don't want any time delays here.  Any suggestions?  
Thanks !

Comment: I found out I can use the 'entityChanged' event (http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html) which fires after the initializer, but it fires after every change of every entity, which means I have to check each time which entity is related to the event and what is the nature of the event; certainly not an efficient solution...  Additionally, I don't know if in future releases of breeze it is guaranteed that this event will fire only after the initializer function is called...

Comment: another workaround I was thinking of is creating an observable with a null value in the extended constructor; in the initializer set this observable to the entity itself; and when creating a new entity, first check if this observable is not null - because the initializer may have already been called and the entity is fully initialized; however, if the observable is null, then add a subscription to this observable so that when the entity will be fully initialized the subscribed function will be called (with the value of the initialized entity in the observable).